# onConfigurationChanged not called at rotation with configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" set?

Tags: android, widget, rotation

I'm not the first one to have problems with getting onConfigurationChanged called at rotation. But since the common solution is to set configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
in the manifest, and that does not help me, I posting this question regardless of the thousands of “similar” ones.

This is a simple widget that turns the ringer volume on and off when clicked. It works fine until the screen is rotated, after that nothing happens on click.

To deal with this issue I want to catch onConfigurationChanged, but it never gets called!
I never get to see the log message from  onConfigurationChanged, I do however see another message in the log “I/ActivityManager(   63): Config changed: ” indicating that the configuration gets changed and that it would be reasonable to expect a call to onConfigurationChanged.

Please help :)

### Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    package="aa.android.x10.mini.mywidget" android:versionCode="1"  
    android:versionName="1.0">  
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
             android:label="@string/app_name">  

    <receiver android:name="MyWidgetProvider" android:label="My Widget">  
        <intent-filter>  
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />  
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED" /> 
        </intent-filter>  
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"  
                   android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />  
    </receiver>  
    <service android:name=".UpdateWidgetService"
             android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"></service>  
    <activity android:name=".Test"></activity>  

    </application>  
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />  

</manifest>
```

---

WidgetProvider:
    package aa.android.x10.mini.mywidget;

```
import android.app.PendingIntent;  
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;  
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;  
import android.content.Context;  
import android.content.Intent;  
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;  

public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider 
{   
@Override  
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,  
        int[] appWidgetIds) 
{  
    Log.i("MyWidgetProvider onUpdate", "#### CALLED!");  

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),  
            R.layout.widget_layout);  
    Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), UpdateWidgetService.class);  
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);  

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 
                                                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.TextView01, pendingIntent);  

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);  

    context.startService(intent);  
    }  
}
```

---

Service:
    package aa.android.x10.mini.mywidget;

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

public class UpdateWidgetService extends Service 
{  
@Override  
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) 
{  
    Log.i("UpdateWidgetService", "#### CALLED!");  

    String state = null;  

    AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);

    if (mAudioManager.getRingerMode() != AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL )
    {
        mAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
        mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING,mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING),AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_ON);
        state = "ON"; 
    }
    else
    {
        mAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
        mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING,0,AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_ON);
        state = "OFF"; 
    }

    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext());  

    int[] appWidgetIds = intent.getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS);  
    if (appWidgetIds.length > 0) 
    {  
        for (int widgetId : appWidgetIds) 
        {  
            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);  
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.TextView01, "\n" +"         "+ state);  
                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);  
            }  
            stopSelf();  
        }  
        super.onStart(intent, startId);  
    }  

    @Override  
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
    {  
        return null;  
    }  

    @Override 
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) 
    { 
        Log.i("onConfigurationChanged", "##### CALLED! #####");  
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

---

Log when rotating the screen:

```
I/WindowManager(   63): Setting rotation to 1, animFlags=0 
I/ActivityManager(   63): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=310/260 loc=en_US touch=3 keys=2/1/1 nav=3/1 orien=2 layout=17} 
I/UsageStats(   63): Unexpected resume of com.android.launcher while already resumed in com.android.launcher
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jon,

`onConfigurationChanged()` is not really meant for `Services`. As `Services` do not have a UI, there is no guarantee that `onConfigurationChanged()` will not fire dependably. It is best to stick this in an `Activity`, as `Activities` are guaranteed to have a User Interface. If you are concerned about your Widget realigning to an orientation change, that is ultimately a job for the containing Activity to handle. This means if the Activity does not rotate, your Widget will not reorient itself.

If, however, you still need to manage configuration changes yourself, then you need to do your checks manually against the `DefaultDisplay` which automatically changes if the orientation changes. This simple check works as follows:

```
Display display = ((WindowManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
if (display.getWidth() > display.getHeight())
    // In Landscape...
else if (display.getWidth() < display.getHeight())
    // In Portrait...
```

Now, the issue you describe, while it manifests itself when the Orientation changes, it is not specifically an Orientation Change problem. If you look at the code for your `onUpdate()`, you will see that you are only handling one widget at a time. The issue  with this is that the default behavior of an orientation change destroys all UIs and recreates them. Since all updates to multiple copies of a Widget happen at once and you cannot determine how the Activity that holds your widget is going to handle orientation changes, you should account for all of your possible appWidgetIds. The following may help:

```
for (int i : appWidgetIds) {
    int widgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
// Set the RemoteViews for the Widget
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget_layout);
// Set the Pending Intent
    Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),
                               UpdateWidgetService.class);  
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);  

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context.getApplicationContext(), 
                     0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.TextView01, pendingIntent);  
// Update the individual widget
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
}
```

Hope this helps.

FuzzicalLogic

Comment: I'm really grateful for your answer!

As a Java and Android noob, I was confident in that since I managed to Override onConfiurationChanged in my service it was going to be called. 
I must say I find it a bit confusing that there is a function to override in the superclass that is... not meant to be used...?

However, I was really hitting the wall here so I'm very relived that you could point me in a new direction, I will try an Activity approach instead!

Thanks!

Comment: Its not that its not "meant" to be used... Its that it is not meant to be used by developers because it is not "guaranteed" to be used. Does that make sense? See ConfigurationChanged is largely dependent on which Configuration did actually Change. Even the Activity lifecycle has several parts that are called, but not guaranteed to be called and don't know when, but will be before this and after that, if at all.... get me?